# Index of row where maximum value is located

Tags: python, indexing, max

I have this list:

```
dCF3v=[[(1.90689635276794, -44704.76171875)],
       [(1.90689635276794, -44705.76171875)],
       [(1.90689635276794, -44706.76171875)],
       [(1.90689635276794, -44707.76171875)]
      ]
```

I'd like to know the index of the row where the maximum value is. In the example above: row index 3.

I already have a code for finding the maximum value:

```
CF3a = (abs(x[0][1]) for x in dCF3v)
CF3 = max(CF3a)
```

If possible I'd like to adapt this code and not have to do the classic `for and if loops`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to keep the indices and the `key` argument for `max` to look for the right value:

```
dCF3v=[[(1.90689635276794, -44704.76171875)],
       [(1.90689635276794, -44705.76171875)],
       [(1.90689635276794, -44706.76171875)],
       [(1.90689635276794, -44707.76171875)]
      ]

CF3a = (abs(x[0][1]) for x in dCF3v)
index, value = max(enumerate(CF3a), key=lambda (index, value): value)
print index,value
```

Comment: I loose the value of max CF3. value=[(1.90689635276794, -44707.76171875)] whereas CF3 should be 44707.76171875.

Comment: @jpcgandre: I fixed that for you

Answer (score 1):

Since your data appears to numerical in nature I would strongly recommend using the [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) module as it is designed in part to do what you're asking.

You can convert your data to a numpy array

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array(dCF3v)
```

and then use `np.argmax` to find the index of the largest value

```
idx = np.argmax(data)
```

This gives you an index into the flattened array. If you know the shape of your array this flattened index is easily converted into a row number using modular arithmetic. You can get the number of rows and columns like this

```
rows,cols = data.shape
```

and then the row number with modular division

```
maxRow = idx%cols
```

numpy also has a function called `unravel_index` which does the modular arithmetic for you,

```
row, col = np.unravel_index(idx, data.shape)
```